# How to enable surface flinger events on logcat

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

I am trying to get surface flinger events on LogCat. Objective is to determine number of unique frames painted each second. Surface flinger source code logs all events of interest(surface frame repaint etc), but LogCat output does not dump them. Is there any way to enable these messages?

So far I have tried 
(i) Reading logcat messages from main buffer (adb logcat) 
(ii) Reading logcat messages from event buffer (adb logcat -b events)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surface flinger events can be dynamically enabled by using following commands on the android shell.
`adb shell "service call SurfaceFlinger 1006 i32 1"`  
`adb shell setprop debug.graphic_log 1`

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-platform/pQeeAH-JP94

Comment: The solution seems to work on my development Android version. Does it work on real devices?

Comment: Have not tried. I guess devices need to be rooted for above commands to work.

Comment: Works on rooted devices, but does not work on unrooted devices (permission issue)

Comment: adb shell setprop debug.graphic_log 1 
and reboot, works for me.